# SQL PDO count rows with 3 param

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have the following code:

```
 public static function check($ip,$op,$page)
 {
$con = new PDO(DBN,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ips WHERE ip=:ip";
$st = $con->prepare($sql);

$st->bindValue(":ip",$ip,PDO::PARAM_STR);


$st->execute();

$counter = $st->fetchColumn();

 $con  = null;
 return $counter;

  }
```

The $counter display the correct number of rows but if I add

```
       $st->bindValue(":op",$op,PDO::PARAM_INT);
       $st->bindValue(":page",$page,PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

$counter appear boolean false;
I double checked my DB but every thing there is fine.I tried to add one of them and the other one but the problem persist;

Comment: Don't you need to have `:op` and `:page` in your SQL statement before you can bind a value to them?

Comment: i put them in statement ' "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ips WHERE ip=:ip,op=:op,page=:page"; '

Comment: The correct is: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ips WHERE ip=:ip and op=:op and page=:page

Comment: You should make sure that you're producing valid SQL, as @fonini points out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can activate the PDO debug and see if there's something wrong with your query:

```
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Thanks I fixed it with using you're tip and ' $sql = " SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ips WHERE ip=:ip AND op=:op AND page=:page ";'